# Spring Integration and TaskExecutors

Tags: spring-integration

In Spring Integration, can a task executor be shared between different channels? Will it impact performance as several channels will now be competing for the same resources, or is it only the definition which is shared?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not just a definition it's a specific TE instance. If you inject it into multiple places, it's threads are shared across those elements.

You can tune the executor's properties (pool size etc) to suit but, if you have a critical component, you can always provide it with a dedicatad TE.

Comment: Thanks very much Gary. When a channel connects to a service-activator/chain/jms:outbound-channel-adapter, etc, should a task executor be configured for those elements as well? Or, will there automatically be as many instances of these of these elements as there is is for the channel which is sending to them?

Comment: No; typically those components are passive and run on the calling thread (when using DirectChannels). The only time you need a task executor is for "active" inbound adapters (such as JMS message driven), or when using polling (polled endpoints or you have a QueueChannel mid-stream). Most components that need a TE provide a default; you only need to provide a specific one if you need to tune the parameters or you want to share it acrosss multiple components.

Comment: For jms:inbound-channel-adapter, what is difference between using the "concurrent-consumers" attribute of jms:inbound-channel-adapter, and setting a task-executor ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the inbound channel adapter is polled and the concurrency is controlled by the polling interval and whether you hand off to a task (via the TE). The message-driven-channel-adapter uses a message listener container and the concurrency is controlled by the concurrency settings. It has an internal TE (or you can specify an external one), but the concurrency controls the number of threads. The inbound adapter (not message-driven) has no concurrency settings.